# LDAP and Symfony : Could not complete search with dn

Tags: symfony, active-directory, ldap, symfony5

I try to pass my application to Symfony. I have a problem with authentication.
With PHP, I used this code to check connection to active directory

```
$ldap_host = "%MY AD HOST%";
$ldap_dn = cn=srv_ldap,ou=Service,ou=Applicatifs,ou=Utilisateurs,ou=DomaineInterne,dc=mydomain,dc=pri";
$ldap_usr_dom = '@mydomain.pri';
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);
ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,1);

// verify user and password
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
```

With Symfony, I used the Symfony Component Ldap :

- config\services.yaml

```
[...]
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
      arguments:
      - host: %MY AD HOST%
        port: 389
        #encryption: tls
        options:
          protocol_version: 3
          referrals: false
```

- config\packages\security.yaml

```
...
[...]
 providers:
        ad_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: cn=srv_ldap,ou=Service,ou=Applicatifs,ou=Utilisateurs,ou=DomaineInterne,dc=mydomain,dc=pri
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: sAMAccountName
 firewalls:
       main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true

           form_login_ldap:
                provider: ad_ldap
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'sAMAccountName={username}@mydomain.pri'
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: blog_index
```

I have an error LdapException with the message :
**Could not complete search with dn "cn=srv_ldap,ou=Service,ou=Applicatifs,ou=Utilisateurs,ou=DomaineInterne,dc=mydomain,dc=pri", query "(sAMAccountName=jane_admin)" and filters "*". LDAP error was [1] Operations error.**

I try to replace "dn_string: 'sAMAccountName={username}@mydomain.pri'" with different things, but I still have this message...